# Ubuntu 14.04LTS boot loader crashes

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am using Win 10 and Ubuntu as dual boot.The boot loader of my Ubuntu continues to crash. I don't know why but it happened 2 times last week and today again.I had to use boot repair to run it again. Can any one tell why is this happening in a weird manner? What could be the possible and permanent(if possible) solution for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem? What do you mean by crash? Do you have Windows update turned on?

Comment: No, Windows Update is turned off. By crash i mean when i boot i get an error warning it says to fix/ignore/manual fix(Does not happen every time only when it crashes) and then what ever i do after boot i can access any file of Ubuntu. And when i reboot i get grub error and then i have to use a live USB and use boot-repair to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think somehow grub got corrupted. There have been reported cases where Windows update messed up grub. You should reinstall grub from an Ubuntu live disc or USB drive. Be sure to use the same Ubuntu version that is installed in your machine.

I have already answered a similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781668/system-wont-boot-anymore-after-software-update) in detail. The same solution will work for you as well. Follow the steps and proceed carefully. Let me know in the comments if you have difficulty in understanding something.

Comment: Thank you. And the steps were well described so no problem with it.